# Clingo: Compare String Literals by Order (Index)?

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

I have defined a color palette called `tableau10` in [Clingo](https://github.com/potassco/clingo):

`tableau10(blue;orange;red;teal;green;yellow;purple;pink;brown;gray).`

Is there a way to compare the colors by the order they appear in my color definition? (e.g., `blue = 0, orange = 1, red = 2, ...`)

My goal is to be able to claim things like `blue < orange`, `blue < gray`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicate `tableau10` is unordered. To do such comparisons you'd have to encode order in one way or another. You could for example assign numbers to the colors `value(blue, 1). value(orange, 2). ...` and compare the associated numbers when necessary, or you could write `lessthan(blue, orange). lessthan(orange, red). ... lessthan(brown,gray).` and also add the transitivity rule `lessthan(A, C) :- lessthan(A, B), lessthan(B, C).`

Comment: Thank you! I understand how to use `lessthan` to compare colors now. Could you elaborate on how to use `value` to compare the numbers associated with each color?

Comment: With the addition of the `value` predicate, `lessthan(blue, gray).` could be expressed as `value(blue, N), value(gray, M), N<M.` You "read" the values to the variables `N` and `M`, and then compare those variables with the clingo inbuilt `<` comparison operator.